# How to implement angular AMD in SystemJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, systemjs

I am currently using requirejs + AMD to load modules asynchronously, but since we are going to migrate our angular 1.x application to angular 2 and above version, I dont know whether system js supports AMD feature or not ?

If systemjs supports AMD, please suggest how can I implement AMD routes (state based) from systemjs in angular 1.5 version.

Routes.js

```
    $stateProvider.
        state('login', angularAMD.route({
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'auth/login.tmp.html',
            controllerUrl: appPath + 'auth/login.ctrl.js',
        })).
        state('home', angularAMD.route({
            url: '/home',
            controllerUrl: appPath + 'home/home.ctrl.js',
            templateUrl: appPath + 'home/home.tmp.html',
        }))
```

In the above code sample, how would I implement same behaviour as **angularAmd.route** do in systemjs ?

I have tried using following code in routes.js file, (after searching alot in google)

```
define(['app', 'login.ctrl.js', 'home/home.ctrl.js'], function(app) { // do code here }
```

**As SystemJS resolves AMD through define/require.**

Please let me know, if you need further details.

Comment: why would you need systemjs? Why won't you use angular-cli? Why would you need to implement some strange behavior in the old system if you need to migrate to the totally different system?

Comment: Actually, I have old project in my company which was written in angularjs + requirejs + amd + grunt. So we try to migrate it to systemjs or webpack but we could not succeed due to already implemented amd and project is too big we can not re-write and our goal is run existing project with angular 2+.

Comment: Yes, SystemJS can load AMD modules. @smnbbrv you are comparing apples and oranges and your statement doesn't make sense. You don't seem to understand the use cases.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I do not understand the use cases, that's why I asked some questions to clarify that. The master of fruits, as long as you think that *Yes, SystemJS can load AMD modules* answers the question and you understand everything, could you post the answer then?

Comment: @smnbbrv there isn't enough detail in this question to answer at present. That said, the use case is presumably lazy loading.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal it all depends on how complex your integration with AngularAMD is. If it is simple, you might just write `window.require = SystemJS.amdRequire; window.define = SystemJS.amdDefine;` since the AngularAMD library uses those methods.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have already done it, but it did not work when comes to angular routing, since routing does not provide lazy loading in angular by default.

Comment: @AmitAgrawal I know that. That's the motivation for AngularAMD. As you know, it uses RequireJS to achieve that. Naturally SystemJS can be used as well, but I can't tell what you have tried because you don't show what's inside the define call

Comment: Please add more detail specifically, can you show a piece of code that you tried to run that did not work with system js and what error received or behavior you observed. It's more than possible to do this and number of ways.

Comment: https://georgedyrra.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/angularjs-with-typescript-and-systemjs/